# In video editing, the rendering becomes an empty screen

Tags: rendering

[image]

In video editing, rendering becomes an empty screen, what's the problem? The encoding values are the same as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Hi somin, this could be a lot of problems. Unfortunately screenshotting just one setting isn't enough, so pls provide blend file so we can check it out on our own. thx.

Comment: hi, unfortunately, i don't know how to upload blender file. how can i do?

Comment: Follow the instructions on https://blend-exchange.com/ . Is this editing an already rendered movie?

Comment: oh, thank you so much! uploaded that file.

Answer (score 0):

you have no light in your basketball - scene.

I just added an area light and got:

[image]

Comment: Oh i already have hdri file in background. Is not work?

Comment: i have no idea because you didn't pack resources before uploading. so i cannot check that

Comment: It's rendering today. I don't know why it didn't work yesterday. Thank you so much for your answer